# What does the string format %80[^,] mean in C?

Tags: c, string-formatting, scanf

Given the following lines:

```
char szInline[80];
char szDescription[80] = { NULL };
float fCost = 0;
sscanf (szInline, "%80[^,], %f", szDescription, &fCost);
```

What does the %80[^,] do?

Comment: btw `{ NULL }` should be `{ 0 }` or `{ '\0' }`. `NULL` is a pointer that has the value 0. Assigning it to a character should be giving you a *"incompatible pointer to integer conversion"* warning.

Comment: @user3386109: Unfortunately, it very likely won't produce a warning. `NULL` expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant, and is commonly `0`. (And yes, the fact that a *null pointer constant* is not necessarily an expression of pointer type is exactly as counterintuitive as you think it is.)

Comment: @user3386109: Even though defining `NULL` as `(void *) 0` is a very popular practice in C standard library implementations, `NULL` is not guaranteed/required to be a pointer. It could be an integer `0`, which will make this code valid. However, your point still stands. `NULL` has no business being there. `NULL` should be reserved to pointer contexts only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read at most 80 chars up to the next `,` comma.

Btw, the `szDescription` buffer is too small by 1.

Comment: Nice catch on the "too small by 1" bug!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Good bug candidate, but no consequences in this particular case since the input string has a maximum length of 79.

Comment: @AnT:  The definition: `char szInline[80];`  If `szInline` is not a proper string (does not contain a null byte), the code invokes undefined behavior.  We all assume the fragment omits the initialization of `szInline`, but an ellipsis `...` would make it more obvious.

Comment: @chqrlie That's a bit optimistic. To me, it looks like the `%80` is intended to compensate for the string being potentially *not* properly terminated.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: that would be insufficient of course. I don't believe the OP had such a contorted case in mind.  He may have been taught how to avoid overflowing the destination array, and was caught by the quirky semantics if the `sscanf()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for `sscanf(szInline, "%80[^,], %f", szDescription, &fCost)`:

- `sscanf` will parse between `1` and `80` characters different from `,` into array `szDescription`,
- if successful, it then expects to match a `,` character ;
- if found, it then ignores any whitespace characters (including `'\n'`) ;
- if finally tries and converts a floating point number representation into variable `fCost` of type `float`.
- It will return the number of successful conversions or `EOF` is case of an early failure.

There are potential problems in there:

- the destination array `szDescription` is too short for 80 characters plus a `'\0'` terminator, but luckily, the input array `szInline` also has a length of 80.  If it contains a proper string, at most `79` characters will be matched by `sscanf`, so no overflow can occur.  The size specifier is actually not needed in this particular case.
- the space after the `,` is redundant. `%f` always ignores leading whitespace.

Beware that `sscanf()` will return `EOF` on this input: `,1` as there are **no** characters different from `,` to be parsed from the start of the input string.  This special case is commonly overlooked by even advanced C programmers.

If you want to accept a possibly empty string before the `,`, you cannot use `sscanf()` directly, but you can use this:

```
/* compute the length of the initial sequence upto `,` if any */
size_t len = strcspn(szInline, ",");
/* len < 80 because sizeof(szInline) == 80 */
/* copying the initial string */
memcpy(szDescription, szInline, len);
szDescription[len] = '\0';
if (sscanf(szInline + len, ",%f", &fCost) != 1) {
    /* conversion error: no `,` or no number past it */
    ...
}
```

`sscanf()` has many quirks, it is notoriously difficult to use properly for anything but the most trivial parsing tasks. Seldom used standard functions `strspn()` and `strcspn()` are useful alternatives.

Comment: Is there a way to make scanf match up to 80 non-comma characters optionally so that ,1 would also be successful?